# WPF ComboBox with image

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to populate a Combo with images. It is defined as:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLangComboItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Where the items are the LanguageItem classes:

```
public class LanguageItem
{
  public System.Drawing.Bitmap Image { get; set; }
  public string Label { get; set; }
  public string Culture { get; set; }

  public LanguageItem(System.Drawing.Bitmap image, string label, string culture)
  {
    Image = image;
    Label = label;
    Culture = culture;
  }
}
```

Now, in my ViewModel c'tor I do:

```
  _Languages = new ObservableCollection<LanguageItem>();

  System.Reflection.Assembly app = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  System.IO.Stream file;
  file = app.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.Images.FLAG1.gif");
  _Languages.Add(new LanguageItem(new Bitmap(file), "ITALIAN", "it-IT"));
  file = app.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.Images.FLAG2.gif");
  _Languages.Add(new LanguageItem(new Bitmap(file), "ENGLISH", "en-EN"));

  this.SelectedLangItem = _Languages[0];
```

The images are embedded resources. Here I have two problems:

1. The images are not displayed;
2. The Item is not selected, the SelectedLangItem is:

   public LanguageItem SelectedLangItem
       {
         get { return _SelectedLangItem; }
         set
         {
           if (_SelectedLangItem == value)
             return;

   ```
       _SelectedLangItem = value;
       this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedLangItem");
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("MyNamespace.Images.FLAG1.gif", UriKind.Relative));
```

as it have to implement ImageSource

And regarding not selected: Property name is "SelectedLangItem" while in xaml SelectedLangComboItem if you did not mistype.

CODE:

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedLangItem");
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLangComboItem}"
```

Comment: Thanks @vitaliy-zadorozhnyy, for the property binding, you're right! It was been a copy-and-paste error!

Comment: Using as path the following works: "/MyNamespace;component/Images/FLAG1.gif"

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you are trying to bind an `Image` to the `Image.Source` property, which is of type `ImageSource`.

The easiest solution is to add your actual image files into a folder and change the `Image` property in your class to a string that holds the file path to the image in this format:

```
/ApplicationName;component/ImageFolderName/ImageName.png
```

Then you can correctly bind this string (which the Framework will convert into an `ImageSource` object) to the `Image.Source` property in your `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I just want to point out that the `Image` property returns a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which is from WinForms. If the property returned a WPF `ImageSource`, this would work properly.

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht, who are you pointing that out to? If it's me (and it seems like it's me as you've commented on my answer)... I know that already, thanks... and if it is the question author, then maybe your comment would be better suited if it were joined to their question instead?

Comment: Hi, thanks to all for the suggestions. I made a little confusion :-) I set ImageSource as type for LanguageItem.Image and change my code as suggested by @vitaliy-zadorozhnyy, but the image is still not displayed.

Comment: Why are you commenting on my answer after implementing vitality's suggestion? All you need to do is follow the simple instructions in my answer to make it work.. but that's up to you.

Comment: @Sheridan, I was just trying to clarify your answer in case there was any confusion over why a string would work, but an image wouldn't (as, the `Image` control should be able to display in image...)

Answer (score 2):

Try below xaml code and bind image list into combobox...

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="cmbTemplate">
            <WrapPanel Margin="0 5 0 5" Height="80">
                <Image Width="65" Height="65" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Photo}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Label Content="Dropdown list with Image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Margin="20"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="lstwithimg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate}" Height="80" Width="400"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Check below... for more understanding of live example...

http://www.codescratcher.com/wpf/wpf-combobox-with-image/

Comment: That is actually the best answer. It's a pitty that it is without explanations and that it contains so much superfluous.