# How can I add some images as drop down in combo box?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, combobox

I have some quick icons which make my software easy to use. But now as per 
  my client requirements, I need to make these icons a Dropdown. Does anyone have some idea how to do this?

I have tried the normal combo box code XAML. But cannot add images. Is there any better way in code-behind or DbModels?

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"
Grid.Column="5"  x:Name="DropDownSearchMode" Style="{StaticResource 
ComboBoxStyle}">

    <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>

</ComboBox>
```

Instead of X, Y, and Z, I want some icons to display a drop-down. Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491205/wpf-combobox-with-image <br/>
It can help you

Comment: @feihoa, This use view-model. I am strictly instructed not to use view-model. I use code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="red.png" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red">Red</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="green.png" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="Green">Green</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="blue.png" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="Blue">Blue</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```